# RTEMS STM32F4 how to use BSP

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32f4, bsp, rtems

I’m very new to RTEMS.
I think to have successfully built RTEMS to run on the STM32F4.
I’ve tried the LED blinking example (trough timer) contained in the examples folder (here: https://github.com/RTEMS/examples-v2/tree/master/led).

I have compiled and flashed it on my board and the led blinked, so I think to have a good setup. Unfortunatly there not exist so much examples about "how to use Board Support Packages (BSP)" in order to program hardware related features.

I want to go further and I would like to use USART in order to have a console useful for debugging and learning.
I really have no clues on how to use the BSP (at code level) to implement USART or more in general, implementing hardware drivers.
What should I define? What I need to call? I can imagine that with RTEMS and the BSP I shouldn’t  write code at “registers level”. Am I right?
Can someone provide me a simple example about it? Can you give me some clarifications on the argument?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Lorenzo

Comment: are you porting RTEMS to this platform or has it been ported already?

Comment: Hi Old_timer,
No, It should be already ported but i cannot find documentation so I'm quite stuck.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most BSPs, one of the serial ports is used for standard input and standard output. So you should be able to use normal POSIX functions (like `printf`) for printing text to that console.

By default, only USART3 is active on this BSP. So if you didn't use any special options, I would assume that one to be stdout. Default baudrate is 115200. The pins should be TX on PD8 and RX on PD9.

From the examples-v2 repository the hello_world_c should do some basic output: https://github.com/RTEMS/examples-v2/tree/master/hello/hello_world_c

If you want to use another USART or UART, you should enable it during configuring your BSP with options like: `STM32F4_ENABLE_USART_1=1` (Note that 4 and 5 are `UART` instead of `USART`)

You should then be able to open all other USARTS and UARTS by just opening for example the `/dev/ttyS1` devices with `open(...)` and using the same `read(...)` or `write(...)` calls like you would on Linux.

Comment: Hello Christian,  
I tried the solution proposed by you and it works! So thanks!  
If can I ask something more, where I can find all related STM32F4 RTEMS BSP documentation?   https://github.com/RTEMS/rtems/tree/master/c/src/lib/libbsp/arm/stm32f4
I cannot find it!  
The solution you proposed is straightforward and simple but where did you learn about?  
For istance, where I can know what is implemented in the BSP and what is not etc.  

thanks again for your time,  

Lorenzo

Comment: BSP documentation is a weak point in RTEMS. Part of it is in README files in the BSP. Some other parts are in the wiki. In this case: https://devel.rtems.org/wiki/TBR/BSP/STM32_F4. More general (not BSP specific) Documentation can be found here: https://docs.rtems.org/. Note that RTEMS implements a lot of POSIX. So you have a C standard library quite similar to Linux. Regarding the question, where I learned about it: I work at embedded brains (http://www.embedded-brains.de/en/) and we are offering commercial RTEMS support. So I can learn during work and from my colleagues. Regards, Christian